# Помогите написать команду для поиска файлов

Tags: linux

Есть огромная папка - "big". В нем идут папки с названием в два символа. В каждой такой папке еще папки с названием в другие(может быть и те же) два символа. А в этих папках папка с названием которая является одинаковым с его дочерней папкой и с названием того самого нужного файла в конце. Также между самим файлом и папкой с таким же названием есть папка "001"

Обьясняю переменными и ссылкой. 
Ссылка: /big/aa/bb/название_файла/название_файла/001/название_файла.jpg

Название_файла это строка в виде "c-efgh YYYY" где "с" это число а "YYYY" это год. Также есть пробел.

Еще раз ссылка:  /big/aa/bb/c-efgh YYYY/c-efgh YYYY/001/c-efgh YYYY.jpg

Нужно написать команду "find" через терминал на линуксе который выведет список ссылок найденных по данным параметрам. Заранее спасибо. Надеюсь смог донести и найдутся те кто поможет решить задачу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет!

Надеюсь правильно понял.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Где ищем: 
BIG_PATH="/path/to/big"

# Что ищем:
# Название_файла это строка в виде 
# "c-efgh YYYY" где "с" это число а
# "YYYY" это год. Также есть пробел.
FILE_PATERN="^.*/[0-9]-efgh\s[0-9]{4}\.jpg$"

# Магический поиск:
find "$BIG_PSTH" -type f -regex "$FILE_PATERN"

# End of script
```

Непольшое пояснение к патерну

-regex опция **find** сравнивает весь вывод с патерном (не нужен **grep**)

```
^ - начало строки
$ - конец строки
[0-9] - любое число от 0 до 9
{4} - повторяется 4 раза
. - точка, любой символ
\s - пробел
\. - буквально точка
```

Comment: да, спасибо,верно но проблема именно в том что я не знаю как написать патерны

Comment: Попробуйте тот, что в ответе или просто добавте несколько примеров в вопрос.

Comment: Я понял патерн спасибо, но для моей задачи тут только одного не хватает...как в патерне указать одинаковые название папок?....поясню снова свою ссылку....во всей ссылке то что есть в "c-efgh YYYY" одинаковые..тоесть по сути в ссылке 3 раза идут одни и теже символы...например /big/AA/BB/6-777 2017/6-777 2017/001/6-777 2017.jpg

Comment: Вем путь до файла нужен ведь? find -type f найдет все файлы рекурсивно, в патерне ключевое значение играет \.jpg$

Comment: Я вчера смог написать нужный паттерн пользуясь вашим ответом. Спасибо)